# Why `GO` integer `uint32` numbers are not equal after being converted to `float32`

Tags: quic-go

Why is the `float32` integer part inconsistent with the original `uint32` integer part after `uint32` integer is converted to `float32`, but the `float64` integer part is consistent with the original `uint32` after converting it to `float64`.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    deadbeef = 0xdeadbeef
    aa       = uint32(deadbeef)
    bb       = float32(deadbeef)
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(aa)
    fmt.Println("%f",bb)
}
```

The result printed is:

```golang
3735928559
3735928576.000000
```

The explanation given in the book is that float32 is rounded up

Analyzed the binary information of 3735928559, 3735928576

```golang
3735928559: 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
3735928576: 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1111 0000 0000
```

It is found that 3735928576 is the result of setting the last eight positions of 3735928559 to 0 and the ninth last position to 1.

And this case is the result of rounding off the last 8 digits

```golang
const (
    deadbeef = 0xdeadbeef - 238
    aa       = uint32(deadbeef)
    bb       = float32(deadbeef)
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(aa)
    fmt.Printf("%f",bb)
}
```

The result printed is:

```golang
3735928321
3735928320
```

Its binary result is

```golang
3735928321:1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 0000 0000
3735928320:1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 0000 0001
```

1. Why float32(deadbeef) integer part is not equal to uint32(deadbeef) integer part? no fractional part after deadbeef
2. Why float32(deadbeef) integer part differs from uint32(deadbeef) integer part by > 1

Why does this happen? If there is rounding up or down, what is the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Because the precision range of `float` is not complete enough to represent the part of `uint32`, the real effective number of digits is actually seriously insufficient.

The precision of `float32` can only provide about 6 decimal digits (after representing post-scientific notation, 6 decimal places)
The precision of `float64` provides about 15 decimal digits (after representing post-scientific notation, 15 decimal places)

So it's normal for this to happen.

And this is not only the `Go` language that will exist, but all languages that need to deal with this will have this problem.